# My C expression must have struct or union type

Tags: c, struct

I have a method that is intended to print out values as per other methods defined. I will post the methods directly involved to reduce the code. However, Visual Studio returns the error

> `expression must have struct or union type`

My code is as below:

```c
int i;
double cat[12];
#define MAX 3
#define GRAMS 64

struct CatFoodInfo {
    int SKU[MAX], CalPerServ[MAX];
    double price[MAX], lbs[MAX], kg[MAX], grams[GRAMS], servings[MAX], costPerServ[MAX], costPerCal[MAX];
} CatFoodInfo;

void displayReportData() {
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        int sku = cat[i + (3 * i)];
        double price = cat[i + (1 + (3 * i))];
        double lbs = cat[i + (2 + (3 * i))];
        int calPerServ = cat[i + (3 + (3 * i))];
        int kg = cat[kg];
        printf("%07d %10.2lf %10.1lf %10.4lf %9d %8d %8.1lf %7.2lf %7.5lf", sku, price, lbs, kg, cat.grams[i], calPerServ, cat.servings[i], cat.costPerServ[i], cat.costPerCal[i]);

    }
}
```

The above code is will return that error. I have tried changing the values on the `printf` from `cat.grams[i]` to `CatFoodInfo.grams[i]`. This gets rid of the error but only zero is returned.

What is the correct way around this or where am I going wrong?

Comment: @DanD.  struct CatFoodInfo has no error but prints out 0 values and that is not the intended output. Below is  the method on the calculation.

```// 11. calculate: servings based on gPerServ
int calculateServings() {
 CatFoodInfo.servings[i] = CatFoodInfo.grams[i] / 64;
}```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't quite clear what's your purpose.

`cat` is an array of doubles, it has no idea about the struct `CatFoodInfo` or its fields, hence `cat.grams[i]` doesn't make sense. For that, `cat` should be a struct of type `CatFoodInfo`, e.g.:

```
typedef struct { 
   ...
} CatFoodInfo;

CatFoodInfo cat;
```

But this change the meaning, now `cat` isn't an array, there is only one element of type `CatFoodInfo`, so you will have problems with the other parts of the code (e.g. `cat[kg]`).

However, to treat `cat` as an array with `CatFoodInfo` elements, you need:

```
typedef struct { 
   ...
} CatFoodInfo;

CatFoodInfo cat[12];
```

But again, you would have to rewrite most of your code, e.g. `cat.grams[i]` to `cat[j].grams[i]`.